# How to return multiple values from an array object as new variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My array looks like this:

```
var points = [{category: "Category A", correct: "0"},{category: "Category B", correct: "4"}];
```

I am trying to see which category has the highest number of `correct`. I started by using `Math.max` on my array map to determine which one is the highest value (which it returns `4`.) But when I try to expand on that return it begins defaulting to NaN.

```
var res = Math.max.apply(Math,points.map(function(k){
    return k.correct;
}));
```

`o.correct` in this instance will return `4`.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/j91nmp4e/6/)

---

What I've tried:

1. Switching my return to `k.category`

   -> This returns "NaN"
2. Treating it as a function and storing both variables in the `Math.max`, this will pull both values of the object, but it does it for both objects in the array.

   `Math.max.apply(Math,points.map(function(k){
   var highestCat = k.category;
   var highestCor = k.correct;
   alert(highestCat + highestCor); 
   }));`

Any ideas on what I could do to be able to store these as 2 separate variables I could reference later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the array and grab the first element

```
var points = [{category: "Category A", correct: "0"},{category: "Category B", correct: "4"}];
var sorted = points.sort((a,b)=>b.correct - a.correct)
var highest = sorted[0];
alert(highest.category + highest.correct);
```

same thing with object destructuring

```
var points = [{category: "Category A", correct: "0"},{category: "Category B", correct: "4"}];   
var {category:highestCateogry,correct:highestCorrect} = points.sort((a,b)=>b.correct - a.correct)[0];
alert(highestCateogry + highestCorrect);
```

Comment: I didn't think about sorting, but after trying to plug this in, it seems to only return `[object Object]`. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4cra3w16/3/). Edit: just saw your edit to the answer.

Comment: When you alert a object it implicitly calls the objects toString method. `sorted` is an array, the default toString on most objects is `[object Object]`, highest is the first element in the sorted array `{category:"Category B", correct: "4"}` again uses the default toString of `[object Object]` since it does not define it's own toString function

Comment: Using  reduce(or any other loops) is faster than sorting

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let points = [{category: "Category A", correct: "0"},{category: "Category B", correct: "4"},{category: "Category C", correct: "1"},{category: "Category D", correct: "5"},{category: "Category E", correct: "0"}];


const max = points.reduce((currentMax,newMax) => { 
return +currentMax.correct  < +newMax.correct ?  newMax :currentMax
})

console.log(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `NaN` because  correct is a `string` and not a `number`. Use `parseInt` function to convert the string into integer

Comment: I'd like to keep it a string so I can compare the value in conditionals later on. ie: `if highestCat = category a`